# Can't insert into SQLite3 using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlite

I'm trying to make a function which inserts a row into the `SQLite3` database using `dictionary`.

I found here, on SO a way to do that, but it unfortunately does not work. There is some problem I can't figure out.

```
def insert_into_table(self,data):

    for key in data.keys(): # ADDING COLUMNS IF NECESSARY
        columns = self.get_column_names()
        column = key.replace(' ','_')
        if column not in columns:
            self.cur.execute("""ALTER TABLE vsetkyfirmy ADD COLUMN {} TEXT""".format(column.encode('utf-8')))
            self.conn.commit()
    new_data={}

    for v,k in data.iteritems(): # new dictionary with remaden names (*column = key.replace(' ','_'))
        new_data[self.remake_name(v)]=k

    columns = ', '.join(new_data.keys())
    placeholders = ':'+', :'.join(new_data.keys())
    query = 'INSERT INTO vsetkyfirmy (%s) VALUES (%s)' % (columns, placeholders)
    self.cur.execute(query, new_data)
    self.conn.commit()
```

EXCEPTION:

```
self.cur.execute(query, new_data)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 1.
```

When I print `query` and `new_data` everything seems correct:

```
INSERT INTO vsetkyfirmy (Obchodné_meno, IČ_DPH, Sídlo, PSČ, Spoločník, IČO, Základné_imanie, Konateľ, Ročný_obrat, Dátum_vzniku, Právna_forma) VALUES (:Obchodné_meno, :IČ_DPH, :Sídlo, :PSČ, :Spoločník, :IČO, :Základné_imanie, :Konateľ, :Ročný_obrat, :Dátum_vzniku, :Právna_forma)
{u'Obchodn\xe9_meno': 'PRspol. s r.o.', u'I\u010c_DPH': 'S9540', u'S\xeddlo': u'Bansk\xe1 Bystrica, Orembursk\xe1 2', u'PS\u010c': '97401', u'Spolo\u010dn\xedk': u'Dana Dzurianikov\xe1', u'I\u010cO': '3067', u'Z\xe1kladn\xe9_imanie': u'142899 \u20ac', u'Konate\u013e': 'Miroslav Dz', u'Ro\u010dn\xfd_obrat': '2014: 482 EUR', u'D\xe1tum_vzniku': '01.12.1991 ', u'Pr\xe1vna_forma': u'Spolo\u010dnos\u0165 s ru\u010den\xedm obmedzen\xfdm'}
```

EDIT: So I've tried to remove ':' from query so it looks like:

```
INSERT INTO vsetkyfirmy (Obchodné_meno, IČ_DPH, Sídlo, PSČ, Spoločník, IČO, Základné_imanie, Konateľ, Ročný_obrat, Dátum_vzniku, Právna_forma) VALUES (Obchodné_meno, IČ_DPH, Sídlo, PSČ, Spoločník, IČO, Základné_imanie, Konateľ, Ročný_obrat, Dátum_vzniku, Právna_forma)
```

And it returns that `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Obchodné_meno`

I don't know where is the problem, could it be in encoding?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `encode('utf-8')` when creating the table, but not when inserting.

SQLite indeed uses UTF-8, but the `sqlite3` module automatically handles conversion from/to Python's internal Unicode string encoding. Don't try to reencode manually.